# Restify - how to make post req

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, server, restify

I'm trying to create an API with Restify but i can't read the body of the request.

This is the code

main.js:

```
'use strict';


const perfy = require('perfy');

perfy.start('startup');


const restify     = require('restify');
const operation        = require('./operation');

// post call for redirect
server.post('/test', operation.status);
```

operation.js:

```
'use strict';



module.exports =
{
    /**
     *
     * @param {Object} req  The request object as received from the middleware
     * @param {Object} res  The response object as received from the middleware
     * @param {Function} next The next function to be called by the middleware
     */
    status: function(req, res, next)
    {
        // Check configuration loading:
        CONF.get()
        .then( SETTINGS =>
        {

                req.log.debug('[TRACKER] The tracker has been requested to send the following data: %s', req.body);

                // Then return 200 if everything is OK:
                res.send(
                {
                    status: 'OK!'
                });

                next();

        })
        .catch( err =>
        {
            // Return server error:
            next(new restify.InternalError('Could not load configuration. ' + err));
        });
    }

 };
```

in postman i call the service in POST:

[Postman POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OE9t.jpg)

Then, it receives the post (returns status: ok) but the logger can't view the body. It is undefined:

This is the result of the log: 
"[TRACKER] The tracker has been requested to send the following data: undefined","time":"2018-01-11T12:06:13.133Z","v":0}

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED with `server.use(restify.bodyParser());`

in the main.js

```
'use strict';


const perfy = require('perfy');

perfy.start('startup');


const restify     = require('restify');
const operation        = require('./operation');

server.use(restify.bodyParser());

// post call for redirect
server.post('/test', operation.status);
```

more info -> [RESTify on Node.js POST body / json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208975/restify-on-node-js-post-body-json)